# Не могу передать строку в контроллер POST методом. ASP MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Собственно запрос.

```
var xml = "example";
function send(xml) {  //отправка данных на сервер
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/Form',
                    data: xml,

                    success: function (responce) {
                        SaveToLocal("s",xml);// префикс s - sended
                        notification("Данные успешно отправлены", "success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, str) {
                        SaveToLocal("u",xml);// префикс u - unsended
                        notification("Подключение недоступно, данные сохранены в локальном хранилище","warning");
                        setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);// функция отложенной отпраки с тайм аутом 30 сек.
                    }
                })

            };
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Form(string xml)
        {


            string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);          
           using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\WriteLines.txt"))

            outputFile.WriteLine(xml);



           // return View();
        }
```

Form должен записать строку в файл. Файл создается, но он пуст. При передаче выполняется блок "success" - значит ошибок при передаче нет. Но вот куда теряется строка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас там в параметре data не указано передающие параметр:

```
data: {
        xml: xml
    },
```

получится должно:

```
    var xml = "example";
function send(xml) {  //отправка данных на сервер
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/Form',
                    data: {
                         xml: xml
                    },
                    success: function (responce) {
                        SaveToLocal("s",xml);// префикс s - sended
                        notification("Данные успешно отправлены", "success");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, str) {
                        SaveToLocal("u",xml);// префикс u - unsended
                        notification("Подключение недоступно, данные сохранены в локальном хранилище","warning");
                        setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);// функция отложенной отпраки с тайм аутом 30 сек.
                    }
                })

            };
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте объект со свойством "xml" на стороне скрипта и передайте его. А на стороне контроллера принимайте класс со свойством "xml". Скорей всего это происходит по причине того, что вы пытаетесь передать пост запросом value тип.